# How can I handle branching calculations in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to find the longest possible path based on how many connections a variable number has, without repeating connections. The way I thought of doing this was creating a list that holds all points that have already been gone through, but when a path ends, and I need to check a new path, all of those old connections remain in the list. How can I restart my list from the initial point?

Putting it in the recursive function itself would just clear the list each time. Is there a better option than using a list?

Relevant code:

```
package testapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

class TestApp {   
    // Store list of objects we have already matched with
    static List<NumberObject> holdingList = new ArrayList<NumberObject>();
    
    //Test objects
    static int[] array1 = {2,2};
    static int[] array2 = {3,1};
    static int[] array3 = {2,1};
    static int[] array4 = {1,1};
    
    static NumberObject eight = new NumberObject(array1, 8);
    static NumberObject two = new NumberObject(array2, 2);
    static NumberObject three = new NumberObject(array3, 3);
    static NumberObject four = new NumberObject(array4, 4);
    // Test objects ^^
    
    public static int longestSequence(int[][] grid) {
        // TODO: implement this function
        // Code exists here not relevant to the problem

        //Setting up a new numberList array for testing
        NumberObject[] newNumberList = {eight, two, three, four};
        NumberObject[] connections1 = {two, four};
        NumberObject[] connections2 = {two, three};
        //Adding connections
        eight.connections = connections1;
        four.connections = connections2;
        
        for (NumberObject s: newNumberList){
          recursive(s);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void recursive(NumberObject object){
            for (NumberObject x: holdingList){
                System.out.println(x);
            }
            
            if (!holdingList.contains(object)){
                holdingList.add(object);
                
                if (object.hasConnections()){
                    NumberObject[] newobject = object.getConnections();
                    
                    for(NumberObject y: newobject){
                        recursive(y);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(holdingList.size());
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(holdingList.size());
                return;
            }
        }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int numRows = 0;
        int numCols = 0;
        String[] firstLine = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
        numRows = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[0]);
        numCols = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[1]);

        int[][] grid = new int[numRows][numCols];

        for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
            String[] inputRow = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");

            for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
                grid[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(inputRow[col]);
            }
        }
        int length = longestSequence(grid);
        System.out.println(length);
    }
}

class NumberObject {
    int[] id;
    int value;
    NumberObject[] connections;
    //Constructor
    public NumberObject(int[] id, int value){
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
    //print statement
    public String toString(){
        return ("NumberOject: Id = " + id + "\nValue = " + value);
    }
    //Check if it has connections
    public boolean hasConnections(){
        if (connections == null){
            return false;
        }
        else if (connections.length != 0){
            return true;
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
    //Return the connections it has
    public NumberObject[] getConnections(){
        return connections;
    }
}
```

Ideally, the image displays what I want to happen.
Instead, all the old branching connections remain on `holdingList`.
it should be noted paths can branch off to more than two other objects.
[image: Flowpath of what I want to happen]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Added all code to show what I'm running. Not all code is relevant however, and you'll need to input a 2D array to make things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the list in a field, you could just pass an instance of a copy of your list to the function as an argument. So the signature of your function `recursive` would look like:

```java
public static void recursive(NumberObject object, List<NumberObject> visited)
```

To hide this implementation detail, I recommend writing two functions, whereby the second function just passes an empty list to the other one.

---

However, I'd choose a different approach since yours acquires as many new lists as entries are in your tree. In the following implementation, you only have one list per "tree end". Moreover, just like in the previous suggestion, this keeps your class stateless.

```java
static List<NumberObject> findLongestPath(NumberObject currentNode) {
        if (currentNode.getConnectedNodes().isEmpty()) {
            List<NumberObject> result = new ArrayList<>();
            result.add(currentNode);
            return result;
        }

        List<NumberObject> longestPath = currentNode.getConnectedNodes().stream()
                .map(PathFinder::findLongestPath)
                .max(Comparator.comparing(List::size))
                .get();

        longestPath.add(currentNode);
        return longestPath;
    }
```

Comment: Can't say I understand all of that, but thanks for helping!

Comment: What do you not understand in particular? If you want to, I can provide a more "beginner-friendly" solution that leaves more advanced language constructs like method references and lambdas out. Feel free to ask. You can also pose questions about the constructs I've used, I'm here to help.

Comment: I understood your list idea, and so I'm playing around with that, but the more efficient implementation is a bit over my head.

Comment: I'll provide a more detailed explanation later this day. Do you know what lambdas and method references are respectively what `.map(PathFinder::findLongestPath)` means? I just want to know how detailed my explanation has to be.